# How to Return To spesific line In Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm total beginner to arduino and doing a small project. I wonder is there any way to return to spesific line. This is the code I use;

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.initClock();
  Serial.println("Ayin gunu (1-7)");  
  while (Serial.available() == 0){}
  x = Serial.readString();
  if (x>7 || x<0){
    Serial.println("Your input is out of range");
  }
```

And I want to return to `Serial.println("Ayin gunu (1-7)");` this line.

One of the other practice that i tried is;

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.initClock();
  ay:
  Serial.println("Ayin gunu (1-7)");  
  while (Serial.available() == 0){}
  x = Serial.readString();
  if (x>7 || x<0){
    Serial.println("Your input is out of range");
    goto ay;
  }
```

And the error I have taken is `"conversion from int to string is ambigious"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <Rtc_Pcf8563.h>
//init the real time clock
Rtc_Pcf8563 rtc;
int a=0;
int x;
int y;
int z;
int saat;
int dk;
int san;
void setup(){
    //clear out the registers
    rtc.initClock();
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //set a time to start with.
}
void loop(){
  if (a==0){
    while (true){
    Serial.println("Ayin hangi gunundeyiz");
    while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
    while (Serial.available() == 0){}
    x = Serial.parseInt();
    if (x<31 || x>0){
      Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
      Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
      Serial.println(x);
      break;
      }
    else if (x>31 || x<1){
      Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=1;
    }
    if(a==1){
      while (true){
      Serial.println("Haftanin Kacinci gunundeyiz?");
      while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
      while (Serial.available() == 0){}
      y = Serial.parseInt();
      if (y<7 || y>0){
        Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
        Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
        Serial.println(y);
      break;
      }
      else if (y>7 || y<1){
        Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=2;
    }
    if(a==2){
      while (true){
      Serial.println("Yilin hangi ayi? (1-12)");
      while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
      while (Serial.available() == 0){}
      z = Serial.parseInt();
      if (z<12 || z>0){
        Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
        Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
        Serial.println(z);
        break;
      }
      else if (z>12 || z<1){
        Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=3;
    }
    if(a==3){
      while (true){
      Serial.println("Saat kac ?");
      while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
      while (Serial.available() == 0){}
      saat = Serial.parseInt();
      if (saat<24 || saat>0){
        Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
        Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
        Serial.println(saat);
        break;
      }
      else if (saat>24 || saat<1){
        Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=4;
    }
    if(a==4){
      while (true){
      Serial.println("Kacinci dakika");
      while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
      while (Serial.available() == 0){}
      dk = Serial.parseInt();
      if (dk<60 || dk>0){
        Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
        Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
        Serial.println(dk);
        break;
      }
      else if (dk>60 || dk<0){
        Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=5;
    }
    if(a==5){
      while (true){
      Serial.println("Kacinci saniye");
      while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}
      while (Serial.available() == 0){}
      san = Serial.parseInt();
      if (san<60 || san>0){
        Serial.println("basarili bir deger girdiniz");
        Serial.print("girmis oldugunuz deger: ");
        Serial.println(san);
        break;
      }
      else if (san>60 || san<0){
        Serial.println("Hatali deger araliginda bir sayi girdiniz lutfen tekrar giriniz.");
        }
      }
      a=6;
    }
    if (a==6){
      //day, weekday, month, century(1=1900, 0=2000), year(0-99)
      rtc.setDate(x, y, z, 0, 22);
      //hr, min, sec
      rtc.setTime(saat, dk, san);
      a=9;
    }
  //both format functions call the internal getTime() so that the 
  //formatted strings are at the current time/date.
  Serial.print(rtc.formatTime());
  Serial.print("\r\n");
  Serial.print(rtc.formatDate());
  Serial.print("\r\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

This is the actual solution to problem. This works great but there is a fatal flaw which is acceptting all the values but that's a question of another thread. But to be exact this line has solved my problem `while (Serial.available() == 1){delay(10);}`.